# Insertion of rows from DatagridView into Database on Row change Event

Tags: datagridview, insertion

I want to insert rows into SQL table from Datagridview in this way -> Whenever any new row is inserted in the Datagridview ,that row is automatically saved in the database when the user goes in another row .And if it is not a new row then nothing should happen.Means there should be some Event which is fired on Row change.
Please can any1 tell which is appropriate event to do this thing.
-Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this on the `RowValidating` event.

If the insertion fails, you can set the eventargs's `Cancel` property to true, and notify the user of the error.

Example:

```
void dataGridView1_RowValidating(object sender, 
   DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    // do something to insert/update row
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    e.Cancel = true;
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = ex.Message;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thnx leppie ,I'm trying it just now and telling whether I cud do or not.

Comment: @Brite Roy: No, not really, but I'll try give example.

Comment: plz give any example sir leppie.. waiting. I've asked so many ppl .no body cud tell.

Comment: @Brite Roy: That is all I can provide, you will have to provide your own logic for insert/update where the comment is.